# Pig Latin - foreach generate method does not work without the first field

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, latin

I am facing a strange problem with pig generate function where if I do not use the first field the data generated seems to be wrong.   Is this the expected behaviour ?

```
 a = load '/input/temp2.txt' using PigStorage(' ','-tagFile') as      (fname:chararray,line:chararray) ;
grunt> b = foreach a generate $1;
grunt> dump b;
      (temp2.txt)
      (temp2.txt)
grunt> c = foreach a generate $0,$1;
grunt> dump c;
       (temp2.txt,field1,field2)
       (temp2.txt,field1,field22)

$cat temp2.txt
field1,field2
field1,field22


pig -version
Apache Pig version 0.15.0 (r1682971)
compiled Jun 01 2015, 11:44:35
```

In the example I was expecting dump b to return data file values instead of the file name

Answer (score 0):

in your example , you use **`PigStorage(' ','-tagFile')`** ,so each line were split by space .

then:

$0 ->field1,field2

$1 -> nothing ,

just use `PigStorage(',','-tagFile')` .

Comment: if you see my example ..  Field 1 is the filename.

Comment: I believe the field ($1) is nothing, why you got filename by 'generate $1' is because '-tagFile' alway show the filename at the first column.

Comment: if you refer to the pig documentation(http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/func.html#pigstorage),
it mentioned "('tagFile') - Add a first column indicates the input file name of the record.".

Comment: Thanks , Documentation also says this  "Source tagging

If-tagFile is specified, PigStorage will prepend input split name to each Tuple/row. Usage: A = LOAD 'input' using PigStorage(',','-tagFile'); B = foreach A generate $0; The first field (0th index) in each Tuple will contain input file name. If-tagPath is specified, PigStorage will prepend input split path to each Tuple/row. Usage: A = LOAD 'input' using PigStorage(',','-tagPath'); B = foreach A generate $0; **The first field (0th index) in each Tuple will contain input file path**"